# Only displays the message intended for entering yes no matter what you input

Tags: python-3.x

When I run this code no matter what I input it always comes out as "I agree!". 
Any help is appreciated!

```
Pizza_opinion = input("Does pizza taste good? ")

if Pizza_opinion == "Yes" or "yes":
    print("I agree! ")
elif Pizza_opinion == "No" or "no":
    print ("I disagree...?")
```

Comment: What was the input you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assuming the conditions check wether `Pizza_opinion` is equal to "Yes" or it is equal to "yes" but what it really does is check if `Pizza_opinion` is equal to "Yes" or if the string literal "yes" is true, which it always is.
Same issue with the elif condition.

The solution would be to repeat the equality check you do with "Yes":

```
if Pizza_opinion == "Yes" or Pizza_opinion == "yes":
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not using conditionals correctly - you cannot use `or` like that (you can, but it doesn't do what you mean). You essentially told Python`if Pizza_opinion equals "Yes", or if "yes" evaluates to True (and it does) then print "I agree "`. Use either:

```
if Pizza_opinion == "Yes" or Pizza_opinion == "yes":
    print("I agree! ")
elif Pizza_opinion == "No" or Pizza_opinion == "no":
    print ("I disagree...?")
```

Or:

```
if Pizza_opinion in ("Yes", "yes"):
    print("I agree! ")
elif Pizza_opinion in ("No", "no"):
    print ("I disagree...?")
```

Or simply:

```
if Pizza_opinion.lower() == "yes":
    print("I agree! ")
elif Pizza_opinion.lower() == "no":
    print ("I disagree...?")
```